# Show infowindow on mouseover event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, jquery-plugins, gmaps4rails

How can I show/hide a Infowindow on mouseover/mouseout event? 
How can I substitue the Infowindow to tooltip like in this site: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html?

Thanks, Luciano

Comment: I already implemented InfoBox which let you customize the infoboxes the way you want (html + css). For your special question, I don't know exactly, but for sure, you should add the behavior using `Gmaps4Rails.callback`