# How to show the infowindow on mouseOver event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I'm upgrading an old Rails 2.1 app and am replacing the google_maps plugin with the Gmaps4Rails gem.  The conversion has been pretty straight forward so far.  The remaining task is to programmatically show and hide the markers infowindows on mouseOver of a list of addresses which I display beside the map.

My question is how do I get a handle to the marker to display the infowindow?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921456/show-infowindow-on-mouseover-event), but it seems to deal with the mouseOver of the marker.  Essentially, I want to use a mouseOver event from an element outside of the map to show the infowindow of a marker.

Any help is appreciated.

This behavior seemed to be built into the google_maps plugin (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There  is  no  builtin  way  to  achieve  this in gmaps4rails. But here are the relevant steps:

1) In your controller

```
 Foo.your_scope.to_gmaps4rails do |obj, marker|
   # Add any custom elements here
   marker.json { :id => obj.id }
 end
```

This will add the id of each element in the Gmaps.map.markers array.

2) In your view

Html:

- add to each side element an attribute with the id of the related object

Javascript:

- Write a js function which retrieves a marker from it's id (basically, loop `Gmaps.map.markers` and check each element's id)
- write a js function which observes your side elements mouseOver. In it's callback, find the related marker thanks to the above function and finally trigger this: `foundMarker.infowindow.open(Gmaps.map.map, foundMarker.serviceObject)`